# Specifying name of apk file in IntelliJ artifact

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, apk

Is it possible to have different names for every artifact build from IntelliJ IDEA 13?

I am building Android apps and I prefer to include the version code and the version name on the apk file name. Is that possible?